# T-SQL make a Column that uses a UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Basically, I made a @table and I want to insert a column that is using a function.

I figure I'm wrong doing    `WHERE etc... AND Column = (function)`

I have the column show up, but not using the function.  How do I insert this logic into an existing table?

```
    USE database
DECLARE @var DATETIME='...'
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100) = '...'
DECLARE @var TABLE 
(
    var varchar (8) NOT NULL,
    var nvarchar(50) NULL,
    varD varchar(14) NOT NULL,
    var datetime NULL,
    var varchar(1) NULL,
    var varchar(1) NULL,
    var varchar(14) NOT NULL,
    var date NULL,
    UDF AS (dbo.UDF(var))
)


INSERT INTO @table stuff, UDF)
SELECT a.stuff, b.stuff, c.UDF
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON a.var = b.var AND b.var<>'ttt' AND b.var IS NOT NULL,
@table c


WHERE
    (   
        b.var<>'ttt' 
        AND b.var IS NOT NULL
        AND b.var <> 'ttt' 
    )
```

Comment: Please show us the full declaration of your table variable !

Comment: Okay!  I'll have to clean it a little because it's somewhat sensitive! Also, we are headed to lunch, so it will be done when I get back.  I appreciate you responding at all!

Comment: Edited...More text for character floor.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, it was in my SELECT that I needed to set the column to the UDF.  I spent a good bit of time looking at it and I found my mistakes.  I appreciate anyone who looks at this!